# Synonymize [graphics] and [graphic]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphics) – 16,518 questions (has synonym: [computer-graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/computer-graphics))

> Graphics are visual presentations. Questions using this tag should also be tagged with the appropriate language and graphics subsystem in use. For more general graphics questions, consider Computer Graphics Stack Exchange (computergraphics.stackexchange.com).

[graphic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphic) – 523 questions

Of the 523 Qs tagged [graphic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphic) 37 are closed and very many more should be. The 486 currently open Qs cover a wide range of visual representations (eg on screen and charts), methods of generating them (from hardware and algorithms to software) and conversion and/or resizing.

There is nothing fundamentally "singular" in any of these Qs and usage is covered by the [graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphics) usage guide about as badly as for [graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphics) Qs:

> Graphics are visual presentations. Questions using this tag should also be tagged with the appropriate language and graphics subsystem in use. For more general graphics questions, consider Computer Graphics Stack Exchange (computergraphics.stackexchange.com)

[graphic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphic) has no usage guide nor wiki of its own at present.
[graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphics) is currently applied to 16,518 Qs, 15,709 of which are open, of which 9 also apply [graphic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphic).

I can't see any good reason why we need a singular tag here. If you're working on 1000 graphics or 1, [graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphics) should be sufficient to describe what you're working on.

Comment: Or just burninate them both? I don't see the reason for any of them.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto [graphics] is too large to burn. That would be a bulk tag removal and is a separate discussion

Answer (score 3):

I agree that [graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphics) and [graphic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphic) are the same and should be synonymized. It is just a pluralization of the other term and does not deserve to be separate tags (Pluralized versions of tags are now disallowed).

Given that graphics is the more well known terminology rather than graphic, I've synonymized [graphic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphic) -> [graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphics). The later tag now has 17,041 questions.